# aws-sdk SNS on NodeJs don't catches error

Tags: node.js, mongoose, transactions, aws-sdk-nodejs

I try to implement a phone number verification by SMS with aws-sdk SNS and Mongoose,

But when I test it with a wrong phone number, like, some gibberish instead of real phone,
the error goes to the console, but then it won't get caught by `catch` and just crashes it all.

Here is my code

```
// requires, etc is above here

const verifyPhone = async (req, res) => {
    const { phoneNumber } = req.body;

    const { userId } = req.user;

    let code = generateCode(6);

    const session1 = await mongoose.startSession();
    try {
        session1.startTransaction();

        const newCode = await PhoneCode.create(
            [
                {
                    userId,
                    code,
                },
            ],
            { session: session1 }
        );

        sns.publish(
            {
                MessageAttributes: {
                    "AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID": {
                        DataType: "String",
                        StringValue: "Testing",
                    },
                    "AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType": {
                        DataType: "String",
                        StringValue: "Promotional",
                    },
                },
                Message: "Your code: " + code,
                PhoneNumber: "65f76fguyg",
            },
            (err, result) => {
                if (!err) {
                    session1.commitTransaction().then(() => {
                        console.log("transaction committed");
                        res.status(200).json({ message: "SMS sent", result });
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                    throw new Error(err);
                }
            }
        );
    } catch (e) {
        await session1.abortTransaction();
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong!", e });
    } finally {
        session1.endSession();
    }
};

module.exports = verifyPhone;
```

I suspect that the issue is in throwing the error from inside of `sns.publish` 's  callback, but I don't understand,  how else I could do that

Also, if I enter right phone number, the SMS gets delivered, I get the response, but then
mongoose crashes, saying

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoTransactionError: Cannot call commitTransaction after calling abortTransaction
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just got to a solution. The solution for me was to promisify the `sns.publish`, after that all went like a charm.

```
const promisifySNS = (args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sns.publish(args, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
};
```

Funny enough, if you use more generic promisify, for any function

```
const promisify = (fn, ...args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fn(...args, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
};

await promisify(sns.publish, opts);
```

that wouldn't work for some reason.